# Putting tikzpictures in section headers

Tags: table-of-contents

Can you put tikzpictures into a section header?

For example, I'm trying to put the tikzpicture defined in the top rated answer of

[LaTeX "under construction", "in work" or "work in progress" symbols](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/188183/latex-under-construction-in-work-or-work-in-progress-symbols)

into my section header. The picture works fine in the main document, but as soon as I put it into a section header, I get a bunch of mysterious errors.

Below I've included some sample code that compiles. However if you replace "\section{test}" with "\section{test \WIP{0.2}}", then the desired "work in progress" symbol appears in the section header, but the compiler spits out tons of error messages I can't parse. Moreover, the symbol does not appear properly in "tableofcontents".

Are there any workarounds for this?

```
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{footmisc}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage[alphabetic]{amsrefs}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[all,cmtip]{xy}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{aurical}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[outline]{contour}% http://ctan.org/pkg/contour
\usepackage{xcolor}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xcolor
\usepackage{array}

\newcommand{\WIP}[1]{\scalebox{#1}{\begin{tikzpicture}[limb/.style={line cap=round,line width=1.5mm,line join=bevel}]
\draw[line width=2mm,rounded corners,fill=yellow] (-2,0) -- (0,-2) -- (2,0) -- (0,2) -- cycle;
\fill (1.5mm,7mm) circle (1.5mm);
\fill(0,-7.5mm) -- ++(10mm,0mm) -- ++(120:2mm)--++(100:1mm)--++(150:2mm) arc (70:170:2.5mm and 1mm);
\draw[limb] (-7.5mm,-6.5mm)--++(70:4mm)--++(85:4mm) coordinate(a)--++(-45:5mm)--(-2.5mm,-6.5mm);
\fill[rotate around={45:(a)}] ([shift={(-0.5mm,0.55mm)}]a) --++(0mm,-3mm)--++
        (7mm,-0.5mm)coordinate(b)--++(0mm,4mm)coordinate(c)--cycle;
\draw[limb] ([shift={(-0.6mm,-0.4mm)}]b) --++(-120:5mm) ([shift={(-0.5mm,-0.5mm)}]c) --++
        (-3mm,0mm)--++(-100:3mm)coordinate (d);
\draw[ultra thick] (d) -- ++(-45:1.25cm);
\end{tikzpicture}}}



\title{TITLE}
\author{Author}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\tableofcontents

\section{test}

\WIP{0.2}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Try "robustifying" `\WIP` with `\usepackage{etoolbox}\robustify{\WIP}`?

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/463237/197451  -- 

Anything inside sectioning commands must be robust or protected using `\protect`, so you need to change you `\newcommand` to `\DeclareRobustCommand`

Comment: @imnothere Thank you! Robustify worked!

Comment: @jsbibra Hmm \DeclareRobustCommand didn't work. Still getting errors. Though, imnothere's suggestion using \robustify did work for some reason.

Comment: And what about using `titlesec` package?